# Keep receiving undefined method for allow_jwt_authentication in Shopify app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Keep receiving the following error on rails build for a Shopify app I'm maintaining and nothing changes since last push other then adidng a bit of html styling and pushing it;

NoMethodError: undefined method `allow_jwt_authentication=' for #

Here is the full output;

Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `allow_jwt_authentication=' for #<ShopifyApp::Configuration:0x000056547a09f2e8> /tmp/build_ea8d2768/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:10:in` block in '
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/shopify_app-21.2.0/lib/shopify_app/configuration.rb:139:in `configure' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/config/initializers/shopify_app.rb:1:in` '
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in `load' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in` block in load'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:318:in` load'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:666:in `block in load_config_initializer' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in` instrument'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:665:in `load_config_initializer' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:625:in` block (2 levels) in class:Engine'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in `each' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:624:in` block in class:Engine'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in` run'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in` each'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in` run_initializers'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/config/environment.rb:5:in` '
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in` require'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in` block in require'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in` require'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!' /tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.6/lib/rails/application.rb:523:in` block in run_tasks_blocks'
/tmp/build_ea8d2768/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
!
!     Precompiling assets failed.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
!     Push failed

I've tried to update the gems and disabling jwt_authentication but still receive the error.

Comment: Let's rule out an obvious theory first :) How do you know that your version of the `shopify_app` gem has not changed? Do you commit your `Gemfile.lock` to source control? Does your build process respect this lockfile? Does your build log contain the version number?

Comment: @JaredBeck I got it working again and had to roll back the updates made to shopify_app, didn't noticed that Heroku updated my bundle and had to ignore it.